# Remplazar el metodo de method=['POST'] en windows

Tags: python, mysql, flask

estaba siguiendo este tutorial en python (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgCfZkR8wME&t=2368s) y me sale que cuando llego a la parte de usar el method=['POST']
me sale que "El módulo crypt no es compatible con Windows" y quisiera saber si hay algun otro metodo para hacer lo mismo sin usar "method"

Aqui les dejo parte del codigo

```
 from crypt import methods
    from itertools import product
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, url_for
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # setting
    app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'
    
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
    app.config['MYSQL_BD'] = 'manuel_bd'
    
    mysql = MySQL(app)
    
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
    
    @app.route('/contact/', methods=['POST'])
    def contact():
        cur = mysql.connection.cusor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts')
        data = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('layout.html', contacts = data)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo es borrar la primera linea "from crypt import methods". En ocasiones esa linea de código aparece sola pensando que se esta necesitando al declarar los metodos en la ruta.

Comment: gracias, habia dejado esta practica a la mitad y con el comentario que me diste funciono.